# Table structure for daily fund data

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I want to store daily fund data for approximately 2000 funds over 20 years or more. At first I figured I would just create one giant table with one column per fund and one row per date. I ran into trouble trying to create this table and also realise that a table like that would have a lot of NULL values (almost half the values would be NULL).

Is there a more efficient way of structuring the table or database for quickly finding and fetching the data for a specific fund over hundreds (or thousands) of days?

The alternative way I've thought of doing this is with three columns (date, fund_id, fund_value). This however does not seem optimal to me since both the date and fund_id would be duplicated many times over. Having a few million data points just for the date (instead of a few thousand) seems wasteful.

Which is the better option? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: 14M rows is not very big.  You are asking about a non-problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the three columns you mention is fine. `fund_value` is the price of `fund_id` on `fund_date`. So `fund_id` and `fund_date` would be the PK of this table. I don't understand what you mean "having a few million data points just for the date..." If you have 20k funds, a particular date will appear in at most 20k rows -- one for each fund. This is not needless duplication. This is necessary to uniquely identify the value of a particular fund on a particular date. If you added, say, `fund_name` to the table, *that* would be needless duplication. We assume the fund name will not change from day to day. Unchanging (static) data about each fund would be contained in a separate table. The field `fund_id` of this table would then be a FK reference to the static table.

To query the value of the funds on a particular date:

```
select  fund_date as ValueDate, fund_id, fund_value
from    fund_value_history
where   fund_date = @aDate
    and fund_id = @aFund -- to limit to a particular fund
```

To show the dates a fund increased in value from one day to the next:

```
select  h1.fund_date, h2.fund_value as PreviousValue,
        h1.fund_value PresentValue
from    fund_value_history h1
join    fund_value_history h2
    on  h2.fund_id  = h1.fund_id
    and h2.fund_date =(
        select  max( fund_date )
        from    fund_value_history
        where   fund_id = h2.fund_id
            and fund_date < h2.fund_date )
where   h2.fund_value < h1.fund_value
    and fund_id = @aFund;
```

This would be a sizable result set but you could modify the WHERE clause to show, for example, all funds whose values on a particular date was greater than the previous day, or the values of all funds (or particular fund) on a particular date and the previous day, or any number of interesting results.

You could then join to the static table to add fund name or any other descriptive data.

Answer (score 0):

The three column approach you considered is the correct one. There would be no wasted space due to missing values, and you can add and remove funds at any time.

Have a search for "database normalisation", which is the discipline that covers this sort of design decision.

Edit: I should add that you're free to include other metrics in that table, of course. Since historical data is effectively static you can also store "change since previous day" as well, which is redundant strictly speaking, but may help to optimise certain queries such as "show me all the funds that decreased in value on this day".